# UIImagePickerController in Landscape iPhone 6-7 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developing one app in only landscape orientation for iPad and iPhone.
I need to use image picker view to capture from camera.
I added extension to the `UIImagePickerController`

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
       if(self.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
           return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }else {
           return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
        }
    }
    open override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And my view controller from where I am opening imagepickerview contains:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
    }
```

It works very fine with all devices except iPhone6+ and iPhone7+
Camera layout strange on these both devices please consider attached screenshot.
[image]

And project general setting is like:
[image]

Comment: Select "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" checkbox at General Tab and then try.

Comment: already checked @AshokKumarReddyPolu

Comment: I just gave you a suggestion, I will get back to you, once get to know the solution

Comment: Okay thank you hope u get the solution @AshokPolu